# How can i remove duplicate string from both arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, duplicates

This is my jsp page.

```
<body>
    <%

        String a[] = {"PAK", "ENG", "IND", "USA"};
        String b[] = {"ON", "UK","IND","ENG","SA"};
        String[] Filterjoined = ObjectArrays.concat(a, b, String.class);
        out.println(Arrays.toString(Filterjoined));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < Filterjoined.length; i++) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < Filterjoined.length; j++) {
                if (Filterjoined[j].equals(Filterjoined[i])) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                if (sb.length() > 0) {
                    sb.append(',');
                }
                sb.append(Filterjoined[i]);
            }
        }
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println(sb);
    %>
</body>
```

Here i'm getting output as `PAK,USA,ON,UK,IND,ENG,SA` but i need to delete string from both arrays if string has duplicated. i.e., expected output is:`PAK,USA,ON,UK,ENG,SA` because IND has duplicated in both arrays so i need to delete it,remaining elements has to display.Thanks for your reply

Comment: Easy way is to create Set and put all items in it. Set does not store duplicates.

Comment: Isn't "ENG" present in both arrays as well?

Comment: How can i use Set for this code ,could you please change my code if possible @Leos

Comment: Replace your code by `response.sendRedirect("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java already has everything you need to do your task without third party libraries, etc. Use the following solution:

```
String a[] = {"PAK", "ENG", "IND", "USA"};
String b[] = {"ON", "UK","IND","ENG","SA"};

/* Convert your arrays to lists */
final List<String> listA = Arrays.asList(a);
final List<String> listB = Arrays.asList(b);

/* Create another list holding 'duplicate' elements */
final List<String> duplicatesList = new ArrayList<String>(listA);
duplicatesList.retainAll(listB);

/* Finally create a resulting list as a + b - duplicates */
final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(listA);
result.addAll(listB);
result.removeAll(duplicatesList);

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: how can i remove brackets [,] from result string

Comment: You cannot literally remove values from arrays in java 'cause arrays are fixed-size. In your case you can just reassign your array:
`final List<String> newA = new ArrayList<String>(listA);`, then `newA.removeAll(duplicatesList);` and finally `a = newA.toArray(a);`

But I'd suggest you using lists instead of arrays if such manipulations appear in your code often...

Comment: just i need the result as:PAK, ON, UK .but i'm getting [PAK,ON,UK].Could you please tell me where to change the code

Comment: Replace `System.out.println(result);` with the desired implementation of printing the results :) You can use your code with `StringBuilder` from the original question or apache's `StringUtils`: `System.out.println(StringUtils.join(result, ", "));`.

Answer (score 4):

This is how to use the set.

```
Set<String> joined = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
joined.addAll(Arrays.asList(b));
String[] joinedArray = joined.toArray(new String[joined.size()]);
```